# Keyboard not working due to which laptop not opening

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a laptop of which the keyboard can not be taken out from. The laptop keys have not been working for approx 8 months. Many keys in my laptop are not working, so I use on-screen keyboard, but once my laptop discharged and to open it I need to click Enter but the Enter key is not working. You can see that in the image too!

[image]

Please, please someone help me with how to solve this issue.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Use a USB keyboard.

Comment: Try the first selection and if that does not work, try the second selection to see if you can get it to start. There may be more than one cause of this message.  You may need to get the machine serviced.

Comment: actually @John this message will go as soon as I will press Enter but the Enter button is not working.

Comment: You need to get your laptop keyboard replaced - I suggest a repair shop.

Comment: ok but is there any alternative? And how much will it cost to get the keyboard replaced?

Comment: As @gronostaj has already suggested, get a plug-and-play USB external keyboard.

Comment: You can get an external usb keyboard for around 10€. Replacement depends but tends to be more expensive